# How to create a PyTorch mutable tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to create a copy of a tensor that will change if the original changes.

```
r = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True)
p = r.clone()
print('before')
print(r)
print(p)
r = r*5
print('after')
print(r)
print(p)

>>>
before
tensor(1., requires_grad=True)
tensor(1.)
after
tensor(5., grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
tensor(1.)
```

I tried with `clone()`, `detach()`, and even simply `p=r`, nothing worked.

**Update**.
Tried `view`:

```
r = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True)
p = r.view(1)
print('before')
print(r)
print(p)
r = r*5
print('after')
print(r)
print(p)

>>>before
tensor(1., requires_grad=True)
tensor([1.], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
after
tensor(5., grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
tensor([1.], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for a is a view(which is a shallow copy of the tensor), numpy also follows this as well, the below contains what you want

```py
test = torch.tensor([100])
test_copy = test.view(1)

print(test, test_copy) # tensor([100]) tensor([100])
test[0] = 200
test, test_copy # (tensor([200]), tensor([200]))
```

Edit: Made some changes and found out the problem

```py
r = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True) # Remove requires_grad if you really dont need it
p = r.view(1)
print('before')
print(r)
print(p)
with torch.no_grad(): # Had to use this if not wont be able to do math ops cause gradients are being tracked
  # Problem here was that you redeclared a new variable of r so you wiped out the previous reference to the tensor
  r.mul_(5) # Simple calculations
print('after')
print(r)
print(p)
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried the same thing and it didn't really work. Please see my update. Maybe I don't quite understand it. What does the `1` inside of `view` refers to?

Comment: Oo, hmm let me test with your example but 1 referes to the size of the copy

Comment: But another thing out of curiosity do you really the gradients for the tensor? Unless you dont really need to track them

Comment: I actually do want the gradients. My goal is to have this copied tensor as a constraint for the original tensor to be in a certain range.

Comment: Hmm then the answer i provided should work, since i added the gradient tracking